# Find indices of array of values in a master array, when values are arrays

Tags: python, numpy, search, indexing

I have a (N,K)-dimensional numpy.ndarray "master", in which I want to find the occurences of several K-dimensional arrays, let's say I have M of them, stored in a (M,K)-dimensional array "search".

Let's say for example N=9, K=2, M=3 and

```
master = array([[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 1], [0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2]])
search = array([[1, 2], [2, 0], [4, -2]])
```

Here what I would like is something like `array([7, 2])` or `array([2, 7])`, because indices 2 and 7 of the master array appear in the search array.

I first tried to use `np.isin` by writing
`np.argwhere(np.all(np.isin(master, search), axis=1)).ravel()`
But this returned the indices where all the values belonged to `search` but not necessarily to the same element...

This other approach seems to work but it uses Python's list comprehension with nested loops so I think this is very sub-optimal :

```py
np.argwhere(np.any(np.array([[np.array_equal(master[i], search[j])
                               for i in range(N)]
                              for j in range(M)]),
                   axis=0)).ravel()
```

Is there a way to do so by only using Numpy standard functions ? I have pretty big entries so comprehension lists are too slow...

Comment: I think you need to use for loop:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break this up into multiple steps.

1. Equality check between each term in `search` and `master` using `==`. To do this elementwise, we need to make `search` a 2D array using `search[:,None]`.
2. Use `all` on axis 2 to perform a logical AND, which checks if the two terms in `search` are both equal to the two terms in `master`.
3. Use `any` on axis 0 to perform a logical OR, which collapses the result to get `True` or `False` values for each term in `search`.
4. Finally, use `np.where` to find the indices.

With named steps:

```py
import numpy as np

master = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 1], [0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2]])
search = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 0], [4, -2]])
step1 = master == search[:,None]
step2 = step1.all(2)
step3 = step2.any(0)
step4 = np.where(step3)[0]  # [2, 7]
```

All together:

```py
import numpy as np

master = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 1], [0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2]])
search = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 0], [4, -2]])
res = np.where((master == search[:,None]).all(2).any(0))[0]   # [2, 7]
```